# Как динамически добавлять дочерние элементы в форму?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку (на скриншотах под номерами) добавлялся дочерний набор элементов в родительский блок с сохранением всей структуры. Более наглядно на скриншотах.
[image: Исходное состояние]

[image: После нажатия 1]

[image: После нажатия 2]

[image: После нажатия 3]

[image: После нажатия 4]

```css
add {
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  input {
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 170px;
  }

  input[type=file] {
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 180px;
  }

  .block1, .block2, .block3, .block4, .block5, .block6 {
    border: solid;
    padding: 5px;
    margin:5px;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: #000000;
  }

  .block1 {
    width: 340px;
  }

  .block2 {
    width:320px;
  }

  .block3 {
    width:300px;
  }

  .block4 {
    width:280px;
  }

  .block5 {
    width:260px;
  }

  .block6 {
    width:260px;
  }

  .add1, .add2, .add3, .add4 {
    display:inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 3px;
    background-color: #e3e3e3;
    border-radius: 100%;
    font-size: 21px;
    width: 26px;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .point, .out, .car, .amount {
   display:inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Форма</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="form">
    <div class="block1">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Дата">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Вид загрузки">
      <div class="block2">
        <input type="text" class="out" placeholder="Исходящий">
        <div class="add4">4</div>
        <div class="block3">
          <input type="text" class="point" placeholder="Пункт">
          <div class="add3">3</div>
          <div class="block4">
            <input type="text" class="car" placeholder="ТС">
            <div class="add2">2</div>
            <div class="block5">
              <input type="file" class="amount">
              <div class="add1">1</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="sub-btn">Отправить</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Что должно произойти, если после нажатия на 2, я нажму на 3? Должен будет добавиться 2->1 или 2->[1, 1]?

Comment: Должен добавиться блок с формой ТС

          <div class="block4">
            <input type="text" class="car" placeholder="ТС">
            <div class="add2">2</div>
            <div class="block5">
              <input type="file" class="amount">
            </div>
          </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете воспользоваться этим алгоритмом:

```js
const blocks = [
  '.block2',
  '.block3',
  '.block4'
].map(blockQuery => {
  const block = document.querySelector(blockQuery).cloneNode(true);
  const addBtn = block.querySelector('[class^=add]');
  block.removeChild(addBtn);
  return block;
});

const amount = document.querySelector('.amount').cloneNode(true);

const addAmount = (e) => {
  e.target.parentNode.append(amount.cloneNode(true));
}

const addBlock = (e, index) => {
  const block = blocks[index].cloneNode(true);
  e.target.parentNode.parentNode.append(block);
}

document.querySelector('.block1').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  switch (e.target.className) {
    case 'add1':
      addAmount(e);
      return;
    case 'add2':
      addBlock(e, 2);
      return;
    case 'add3':
      addBlock(e, 1);
      return;
    case 'add4':
      addBlock(e, 0);
      return;
  }
})
```

```css
add {
  cursor: pointer;
}

input {
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 170px;
}

input[type=file] {
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 180px;
}

.block1,
.block2,
.block3,
.block4,
.block5,
.block6 {
  border: solid;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #000000;
}

.block1 {
  width: 340px;
}

.block2 {
  width: 320px;
}

.block3 {
  width: 300px;
}

.block4 {
  width: 280px;
}

.block5 {
  width: 260px;
}

.block6 {
  width: 260px;
}

.add1,
.add2,
.add3,
.add4 {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 3px;
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
  border-radius: 100%;
  font-size: 21px;
  width: 26px;
  text-align: center;
}

.point,
.out,
.car,
.amount {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Форма</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="form">
    <div class="block1">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Дата">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Вид загрузки">
      <div class="block2">
        <input type="text" class="out" placeholder="Исходящий">
        <div class="add4">4</div>
        <div class="block3">
          <input type="text" class="point" placeholder="Пункт">
          <div class="add3">3</div>
          <div class="block4">
            <input type="text" class="car" placeholder="ТС">
            <div class="add2">2</div>
            <div class="block5">
              <input type="file" class="amount">
              <div class="add1">1</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="sub-btn">Отправить</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

### UPD

Если немного изменить дизайн добавления после нажатия на 1, то код можно сократить ещё больше и это даже будет быстрее работать:

```js
const blocks = [
  '.block2',
  '.block3',
  '.block4',
  '.block5'
].map(blockQuery => {
  const block = document.querySelector(blockQuery).cloneNode(true);
  const addBtn = block.querySelector('[class^=add]');
  block.removeChild(addBtn);
  return block;
});

const addBlock = (parentBlock, originalBlock) => {
  const block = originalBlock?.cloneNode(true);
  parentBlock.append(block || '');
}

const classToBlock = {
  add1: blocks[3],
  add2: blocks[2],
  add3: blocks[1],
  add4: blocks[0],
};

document.querySelector('.block1').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  addBlock(e.target.parentNode.parentNode, classToBlock[e.target.className]);
})
```

```css
add {
  cursor: pointer;
}

input {
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 170px;
}

input[type=file] {
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 180px;
}

.block1,
.block2,
.block3,
.block4,
.block5,
.block6 {
  border: solid;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #000000;
}

.block1 {
  width: 340px;
}

.block2 {
  width: 320px;
}

.block3 {
  width: 300px;
}

.block4 {
  width: 280px;
}

.block5 {
  width: 260px;
}

.block6 {
  width: 260px;
}

.add1,
.add2,
.add3,
.add4 {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 3px;
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
  border-radius: 100%;
  font-size: 21px;
  width: 26px;
  text-align: center;
}

.point,
.out,
.car,
.amount {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Форма</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="form">
    <div class="block1">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Дата">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Вид загрузки">
      <div class="block2">
        <input type="text" class="out" placeholder="Исходящий">
        <div class="add4">4</div>
        <div class="block3">
          <input type="text" class="point" placeholder="Пункт">
          <div class="add3">3</div>
          <div class="block4">
            <input type="text" class="car" placeholder="ТС">
            <div class="add2">2</div>
            <div class="block5">
              <input type="file" class="amount">
              <div class="add1">1</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="sub-btn">Отправить</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Обновил алгоритм, теперь он гораздо меньше, понятнее и быстрее